# Use openAPI 3.0 extends without using discriminator

Tags: java, jackson, openapi, openapi-generator

Is it possible to have this generated by openAPI without using the discriminator? The reason is that I'm having a lot of trouble getting Jackson to serialize a json that does not have the discriminaotry value. So I wanted a workaround, and by having a simple class BaseClass, I can manually specify the type(I know it beforehand)

```
public abstract BaseClass{}

public Employee extends BaseClass {...}
```

This code below works but it uses discriminator and Jackson keeps throwing property not found for the discriminator:

```
components:
  schemas:
    BaseClass:
      type: object
      required:
        - entityType
      properties:
        entityType:
          type: string
          enum:
            - Employee
      discriminator:
        propertyName: entityType

Employee:
  allOf:
    - $ref: "#/components/schemas/BaseClass"
  properties:
    anotherThing:
      type: string
```

OR is there a way for openAPI to extend a class that has been defined in the classpath? Like I could manually define BaseClass in the src/java and have OpenAPI generate the Employee extends BaseClass thing

Answer (score 0):

The OpenAPI Specification does not natively deal with or know about types, supertypes, subtypes, interfaces or inheritance. Everything is a mapping between the JSON Schema constraint language used to describe the request and response payloads and an either typed or untyped code-gen target language. You can do raw composition using `allOf` (`oneOf`, `anyOf`and `not` are much harder to do code-gen for). If you use OpenAPI v3.1 you might get OK results from schemas using simple `if`/`then`/`else` structures - you can replicate the behaviour of `discriminator` by using `if` schemas with `const` conditions.

It all depends on the code-gen tool you are using and the sophistication of its AST evaluator or templates.

Comment: I was using spring generator